# Receving an error when calling WCF using a Service Moniker in Excel

Tags: c#, .net, vba, wcf

I have a WCF webservice running that has 2 endpoints (mex and wsHttpBinding). The webservice is hostend on the address: http://localhost:2412/Service1.svc and its contact is named "WcfService1.IService1"

I want to call this service from VBA in Excel. To that, I use the folowing code:

```
mexMonikerString = "service:mexAddress='http://localhost:2412/Service1.svc/mex'"
mexMonikerString = mexMonikerString + ", address='http://localhost:2412/Service1.svc'"
mexMonikerString = mexMonikerString + ", binding=WSHttpBinding_IService1"
mexMonikerString = mexMonikerString + ", contract=IService1"

Set service = GetObject(mexMonikerString)
```

When I try to execute this code I recieve the folowing Excel error message: 
Run-time error '-2147221020 (800401e4)'

Does anybody know what the cause of this error is and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Calling WCF Services from Excel VBA clients using the WCF Service Moniker](http://damianblog.com/2009/07/05/excel-wcf/). It has a section on debugging that shows the same error code you are receiving and how to get the actual error description('Interface not found' in this case).

Comment: Using the debuging method described in link solved the problem. There was a problem with the specification of the WCF interface

Comment: I have now also wrote an article about (debugging) WCF services and VBA code, in which I introduce an alternative to using the Visual Studio debugger http://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2010/10/05/using-a-service-moniker-to-communicate-between-legacy-com-applications-and-new-net-applications/

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below format :)

```
Dim addr As String
addr = "service:mexAddress=""http://localhost:2412/Service1/mex"","
addr = addr + "address=""http://localhost:2412/Service1.svc/"","
addr = addr + "contract=""IService1"", contractNamespace=""http://tempuri.org/"","
addr = addr + "binding=""WSHttpBinding_IService1"", bindingNamespace=""http://tempuri.org/"""

Set service = GetObject(addr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to publish WCF service in your IIS.